# Use Google custom urls with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I use Wordpress and I would like to track some links that I post on the internet with Google analytics. I use [Analytics custom campaign](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863) but I get a 404 error.
For example, the page http://mywordpresswebsite.com/some_page exists and works great but if I try to use http://mywordpresswebsite.com/some_page?utm_source=lc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=my_campaign as suggested by Google, I get a 404 error. I searched on the web for over an hour but found nothing. Have anybody had the same problem before?

Comment: Are you using via a Google Analytics wordpress plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using the GA plugin

Comment: Can you check if the site url and home url are both same? as in both with 'www' or without it. 

Also which version of wordpress and which plugin are you using? Kindly share the permalinks structure as well.

Comment: I use Wordpress 3.8.1. The site url and home url are the same (I always use 'www'). For the permalinks structure, I use "Post name" as common settings and "Custom base" as product permalink base.

Comment: can you share the url of the site? I can check for any particular issues.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. Actualy, http://mywordpresswebsite.com/some_page was not a real page but only a redirection (made with a wordpress plugin). That's why it didn't work. It works with a real page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy, mywordpresswebsite.com/some_page was not a real page but only a redirection (made with a wordpress plugin). That's why it didn't work. It works with a real page.